# When does -Wmissing-field-initializers triggers warning?

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-warning

I know as the name says, it triggers when there are missing field initializers. But it didn't trigger any warnings for the following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct test {
    int a, b, c;
};

void func(struct test test) {
    printf("%d, %d, %d\n", test.a, test.b, test.c);
}

int main() {
    func((struct test) {12, .a = 1, 12, .a = 13, .b = 13});
    return 0;
}
```

It compiles with no warnings when I run `gcc test.c -Wmissing-field-initializers` . And it prints out `13, 13, 0`. Is this the default behaviour of `-Wmissing-field-initializers`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gcc.1.html):

This option **does not warn about designated initializers**

try

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct test {
    int a, b, c;
};

void func(struct test test) {
    printf("%d, %d, %d\n", test.a, test.b, test.c);
}

int main() {
    func((struct test) {1, 2}); // Now you get a warning
    return 0;
}
```